# Are React native apps deployable without stores?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-studio, expo

I have a react native project that I did using expo and I want to deploy it on Android and ios forba client, is it possible to do so without the need of app store or play store, I know it's possible for Android to export it as apk, but what about ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. In order to let your client use the app you must submit it to the App Store.

If you don't want your app to be publicly available, you can use [Unlisted App Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/).

There are other ways to install the build of your app to your client's device  without submitting it to the App Store but they have caveats:

- If you are an organization and your client is the employee of the same organization, you can use Enterprise Developer Program.
- If you just want to show them a work-in-progress build to get feedback, use Test Flight (Apple Developer Program elrollment is required). Test Flight builds expire after 90 days.